# how to keep image quality when img element using transform in css?

Tags: css, image, transform, css-transforms

When I rotate image with using CSS transform, image is going to low quality.can I keep image quality after image rotated only using CSS?

```css
.rotate {
       margin-right: 100px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(5deg);
          transform: translate(2px, 1px) rotate(5deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAjV9.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" class="rotate"/>


  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAjV9.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />
</div>
</br></br>
<div>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3NdJ.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" class="rotate" width="150px" height="150px"/>


  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3NdJ.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" width="150px" height="150px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: That's just the browser's antialiasing. The image looks pretty low quality to start with.

Comment: Updated @Jared ! I added high quality of image.but not change.

Answer (score 1):

This is an *anti aliasing* issue of the browser.You can add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the element being rotated which triggers antialiasing on the element.

Comment: After adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the element,But not change more differently.Thank your answer

Comment: You wont be witnessing more changes, the jagged boundaries of the image will be smooth

Comment: Really worked boundaries are smooth.But not keep quality of Image :(

Comment: Yea, it won't anti alias lines on the image.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I found a solution: `border-radius: 5px`